# Angular passing parameters to a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following HTML, running the following directive. I need to pass the `loop` parameter to the directive template. But for some reason its not working. Why?

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <list-element loop></list-element>
</ul>
```

**ANGULAR**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('listElement', function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: 'list-element.html',
        scope: {},
        link: {
            scope.loop : vm.list
        }
    };
});
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<li ng-repeat="(slug, label) in loop">
    <strong>{{ slug }}</strong> - {{ label }}
</li>
```

Comment: That's not valid syntax. Check the documentation on `scope` and `link` you seem to have a misunderstanding here...

Comment: What is `vm.list`? Is that the list of items that you want to display? If so, how does it get populated? You seem to be missing some pieces, like a controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <list-element loop="vm.list"></list-element>
</ul>
```

Angular:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('listElement', function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: 'list-element.html',
        scope: {
            loop: '='
        }
    };
});
```

I'm guessing on the loop="vm.list" thing because I don't know about the rest of the code.  But the idea is that you want to pass the object as an attribute named 'loop'.

Answer (score 0):

Isolated scope two way binding is done as below:

```
scope:{
    loop:'='
}
```

You may go through the angular developer guide [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<ul>
   <list-element loop ></list-element>
</ul>
```

**Angular Directive**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('listElement', function(){
return {
    templateUrl: 'list-element.html',
    scope: {
    },
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.loop = vm.list
    }
};
});
```